# Reasking Android/iOS permissions in case the user refused in the first place

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a Unity application right now. And we have Vuforia based AR stuff (so we need camera permission) as well as geolocated features (location permission needed here).
When I install my app, I get asked for those permissions, so that's ok. But what if I decline ? The app still launches and I can use it... As long the camera and location features are not needed...

How can I display the same permission dialog again to my user, ideally through C# code, whenever he clicks on a button that leads to one of these features ?

If this is not possible, what should I do ? Because right now, the only way to get those alerts being displayed again is to leave and launch the app again...

Thanks for any help on this !

Vinny

Answer (score 1):

On iOS, you can't - once user declines, it's not possible for you to spam them with permissions dialog.

What you can do is explain the user that they need to grant the app certain permissions, and display a button taking them to application settings. You can open application's settings on your device like so (Swift)

```
guard let url = URL(string: "App-Prefs:") else { return }
UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
```

or in C#

```
Application.OpenURL("App-Prefs:");
```